# Make part of Listview`s Header-/FooterView selectable

Tags: android, listview, focus, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with a custom footer set via

```
list.addFooterView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_footer_view, null, true), null,true);
```

list_footer_view.xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" android:focusable="false">
<LinearLayout android:onClick="onProfileClick"
    android:focusable="true" android:clickable="true">
    <TextView android:text="@string/footer_text"
        style="@style/Text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
... other views which should not be focusable

 </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, in non-touch-mode only the whole footer gets selected. As you see I have already tried to manipulate the selection behavior via the `descendantFocusability` and `focusable` attributes. Without success. In touchmode clicking the first `LinearLayout` works.

I have also tried with setting the third `addFooterView` parameter to false.

How can you select only child-elements of the footer-view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also call setItemsCanFocus(true) on ListView. So there are actually two things needed to be done:

1. android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" for header and footer ViewGroups
2. setItemsCanFocus(true) for the whole ListView (you may want to set android:focusable="false" and   android:focusableInTouchMode="false" for the row ViewGroup

You may also need to set focusable="true" for your elements you need to be focusable. Here's an example:

poi_details_buttons.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <View style="@style/Poi.DetailsSeparator" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/show_all_comments"
    style="@style/Poi.DetailsItem"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_forward"
    android:hint="@string/poi_details_show_all_comments"
    android:text="@string/poi_details_show_all_comments" />

  <View style="@style/Poi.DetailsSeparator" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/report_bug"
    style="@style/Poi.DetailsItem"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_forward"
    android:hint="@string/poi_details_report_bug"
    android:text="@string/poi_details_report_bug" />

  <View style="@style/Poi.DetailsSeparator" />

</LinearLayout>
```

PoiFragment.java:

```
      protected View createView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    list = (ListView) (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.poi_details, container, false);

    // allow buttons in header/footer to receive focus (comment_row.xml has focusable=false
    // for it's element, so this will only affect header and footer)
    // note: this is not enough, you should also set android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    list.setItemsCanFocus(true);

...

    View buttonsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.poi_details_buttons, null);
    buttonsView.findViewById(R.id.show_all_comments).setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonsView.findViewById(R.id.report_bug).setOnClickListener(this);

    list.addFooterView(buttonsView, null, false);

    return list;
  }
```

Comment: i'll try this later sometime and report back