# How can I get the ListView Header to be selectable?

Tags: android

I have a Header added to my ListView.
It appears fine, but no matter what I try, to get
it to be selectable, nothing is working.

Currently I'm doing:

```
hazardHeaderView =
    (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.warning_header, null);

hazardHeaderView.setClickable(true);
```

And I have an `OnClickListener` set up for it,
but the `Log` message I have there never gets called.

What do I have to do to be able to detect that
the user has clicked on the Header?

I've tried several variations to the above
but nothing's working.

Thanks!

Comment: header means separator or else ?? can you post the screenshot

Comment: Are you setting onClickListener to hazardHeaderView ? Please add code from onClick() method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442527/make-part-of-listviews-header-footerview-selectable
This post should help you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are inflating a second warning_header. Is it possible that the view which is displayed is not the one on which you attached the `OnClickListener`.

To get the view which is displayed and is part of an activity use `Activity.findViewById(R.id...)` or `View.findViewById(R.id...)`.

Comment: I re-looked at the code on the link above, and tried adding:          android:onClick="onHazClick"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"                                            to the LinearLayout in my Header XML, and it worked!                It called into my onHazClick()                                  Thanks for your help.